# Can you suggest library for minimap component for process diagram?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jsplumb

I am using [**jsPlumb**](http://jsplumb.org/jquery/demo.html) for creating a process diagram editor and I am looking to implement minimap feature which looks something like this [**Screenshot**](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/107176/example-shot1.png).

Can you suggest HOW-TO or what plugin to use? Also I am not using canvas, instead its jquery+SVG+css as jsPlumb defines.

Comment: The link seems not to work. Could you perhaps update us on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try this plugin, they even have an example with JsPlump

Plugin : http://www.magnoliyan.com/mini-map/

Example : http://www.magnoliyan.com/mini-map/demos/window.html

```
//init jsPlumb toolkit
jsPlumb.bind("ready", function() {
    jsPlumb.setRenderMode(jsPlumb.SVG);
    jsPlumbDemo.init();
    // make all the element divs draggable
    jsPlumb.draggable(jsPlumb.getSelector(".element"), {
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            //update MiniMap after an element is moved
            $(window).mgMiniMap('update');
        }
    });
});
$(window).load(function(){
    //init MiniMap
    $(window).mgMiniMap({elements: '.element',draggable: true});
});
```